# how to handle space in variable batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have batch file which is prompting user to provide file name. File can or   can't have space. My batch is failing if my file name has space in it. For example:

```
SET TDSX=.txt    
SET /p DS=%1    
move C:\Working\YAHAMA\DEV\Script\%DS%%TDSX% C:\Working\YAHAMA\NEW_FO
```

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Use code blocks for code.

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around variable assignment like this:

```
set /p "DS=%~1"
```

The squiggly `~` thing removes any quotes from the argument. The above assumes that the file name on the command line has quotes around, otherwise, it's not a single argument as far as cmd is concerned, you may need:

```
set /p "DS=%*"
```

Comment: Hey i just tried the way you said but it is not liking it
SET TDSX=.txt
SET /p "DS=%~1"
move C:\Working\DEV\Script\%DS%%TDSX% C:\Working\NEW_FO

Comment: @SaketKrishna each single parameter that contains spaces must be surrounded with quotes `move "C:\Working\DEV\Script\%DS%%TDSX%" C:\Working\NEW_FO`

Answer (score 1):

You need to protect the spaces in the resultant file and directory names using doublequotes too:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "C:\Working\YAHAMA" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "TDSX=.txt"
Set /P "DS=%~1"
If Exist "DEV\Script\%DS%%TDSX%" (
    If Not Exist "NEW_FO\" MD "NEW_FO"
    Move "DEV\Script\%DS%%TDSX%" "NEW_FO"
)
```